# Showing that $(R/I)/(J/I)\cong R/J$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Choose ideals $I,J$ in a ring $R$ with $I\subset J$. I know that $J/I$ is an ideal in the ring $R/I$. So it makes sense to look at the map $$\phi: (R/I)/(J/I)\rightarrow R/J,\quad (x+I)+(J/I)\mapsto x+J.$$

I want to show that this is an ring-isomorphism.

1. well-defined: Let $(x-x')+I=(x+I)-(x'+I)\in I$. Then...
2. $\phi$ is a homomorphism is clear
3. surjectivity is clear
4. $\phi(1)=1$ is clear
5. $\phi((x+I)+J/I)=0\Rightarrow x+J=0\Rightarrow x\in J\Rightarrow...$

I need now help with $1.$ and $5.$ please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two ideals in R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82478/two-ideals-in-r)

Comment: While the two Questions are close enough to merge, in my opinion marking the older Q as a duplicate of this "newer" one makes more sense because this Question is better written.  Both have one Answer, and these are both of a "hint" type presentation.  So I think merging them makes the most sense, with this one as the target.  I'll flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Define a map $$\phi: R/I \to R/J$$
by $\phi(a+I)=a+J$. This is well defined for if $a_1+I=a_2+I$, then $a_1-a_2 \in I \subset J$ and hence $a_1+J=a_2+J$. Show that this is a homomorphism.

Kernel $\phi=\{a+I: a+J \in J\} =\{a+I: a\in J\}=J/I$

Use Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem to conclude.